# How do I get more control over the NodePorts my Service assigns to my Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I have a Deployment with 5 replicas. All have ssh and telnet. They should not be load balanced. I would like each to select from a predictable list of 5.

Here is my Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myapp:1.0
        ports:
        - name: ssh
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 22
        - name: telnet
          protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 23
```

This is my Service with invalid nodePort values for illustrative purposes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: ssh
    port: 22
    nodePort: [30022, 30122, 30222, 30322, 30422, 30522]
  - name: telnet
    port: 23
    nodePort: [30023, 30123, 30223, 30323, 30423, 30523]
```

I am hoping to be able to accomplish 2 things:

1. Each pod replica instance will only get an ssh port from [30022, 30122, 30222, 30322, 30422, 30522] and a telnet port from [30023, 30123, 30223, 30323, 30423, 30523]
2. A pod replica instance that gets an ssh port of 30022 also gets the telnet port 30023. A pod replica instance that gets an ssh port of 30122 gets a telnet port of 30123 and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you use a StatefulSet instead of a Deployment, and create a unique service per pod that selects for the unique label predictably generated for each pod? See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-name-label

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. If you make it an Answer (and expand on it a bit so the mods don't delete it) I can accept it.

Comment: [Done!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567103/1061413)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset) instead of a Deployment:

> Like a Deployment, a StatefulSet manages Pods that are based on an identical container spec. Unlike a Deployment, a StatefulSet maintains a sticky identity for each of their Pods. These pods are created from the same spec, but are not interchangeable: each has a persistent identifier that it maintains across any rescheduling.

The particularly useful feature of StatefulSets is that you will get a unique label predictably generated for each pod:

> When the StatefulSet controller creates a Pod, it adds a label, `statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name`, that is set to the name of the Pod. This label allows you to attach a Service to a specific Pod in the StatefulSet. [[source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-name-label)]

Then you would create **five** distinct Services, one for each pod, of the following form:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-${n}
  labels: { ... } # whatever you want
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector: 
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: myapp-${n} # assuming you keep the name
                                                   # "myapp" and just switch kind
                                                   # from Deployment to StatefulSet
  ports:
  - name: ssh
    port: 22
    nodePort: 30${n}22
  - name: telnet
    port: 23
    nodePort: 30${n}23
```

replacing `${n}` with `0` through `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that the concept of *"Replica"* means that is going to be the same as the others; a *clone*.

Based on your question, you need to have unique objects, based on a template, so neither `Deployment` nor `StatefulSet` could help as these rely on a `ReplicaSet`.

As for the `StatefulSet` labels approach, I'd rather say that is more like a *many-to-one* relationship, meaning that the whole `Service` is going to be linked to a particular pod. This means that all the ports mapped in the `NodePort` service are going to serve an specific pod in the set. If my understanding is correct, you rather want a *one-to-one* relationship between exposed ports and pods.

Since services act like a load balancer, routing incoming requests to the exact same target (port) on each backend (replica from a deployment), the kind of uniquess that you need might be best approached having each separately, as `Deployment` or `StatefulSet` with their corresponding `NodePort` service and mapping your ports according to your need for **each case**.

This approach of course has a high operational overhead but can cope with the level of uniqueness that your use case requires.

Comment: Thanks! This helped my understanding. For my purpose right now I went with Amit's suggestion of a single statefulset and multiple services. I made a StatefulSet with 5 replicas and 5 unique services that look for the predictable pod names myapp-0, myapp-1, myapp-2, myapp-3 and myapp-4.